# Share a Word template with keyboard shortcuts to macros?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, macros

I prepared a template in MSWord that I want to share with colleagues who are not very tech-savvy. The template has not only styles but also a number of quality-of-life macros that are bound to specific keyboard shortcuts (e.g., alt+r will reformat a paragraph in a certain way).

How can I share this template most effectively? I can save as template.docm but that doesn't share the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Any template with keyboard shortcuts will have them available in documents based on the template. In my page on templates I explain this fully. In brief:

> Templates are a special type of Word document that can hold text, styles, macros, keyboard shortcuts, custom toolbars, QAT and Ribbon modifications,  and Building Blocks including AutoText entries. A document created using a template will have access to all of these features and a large part of your job in creating a new document will be done for you if your templates are well thought out. You don't need to use all (or even any) of these features for templates to help you and those with whom you work. There are document templates, that share these resources with documents based on the template, and global templates that share resources with all documents. [Templates in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm)

You need to make sure that you save the keyboard shortcut in the template rather than in your normal template. *(The normal template should not be shared.)*

You can share all off the things listed except styles by saving a template as a "global template" in the user's Word Startup Folder. The simplest way to share styles outside of using the template as a document template, is to save them as a Quick Style Set. If you want to try that comment and I will expand on how that is done.

It is possible to share styles in a global template by using macros and I can help with that, too, if you want. I can also provide more information on how to set/find the Word startup folder.

**Takeaway: Make sure you save any customizations you want to share in your template. There can be other locations where Word would like to save them. Note that you can share QAT icons for your macros as well. Again, make sure you store them in the template that holds the macros.**